# Calculate and append rows in a swift Dataframe

Tags: swift, dataframe

I've a swift Dataframe, which contains two columns. 1st column is a list of station names (String), the second column contains some values (Double).

How can I group the dataframe arcording to the station names and calc the mean / min / max of the values column in seperate columns and append it to the grouped dataframe?

See the example code:

```
import Foundation
import TabularData

let station_names=["S1","S2","S3","S4","S5"]

var stations:[String] = []
var values:[Double] = []

for _ in 1 ... 100 {
  stations.append(station_names.randomElement()!)
  values.append(Double.random(in: 1.0 ... 25.0))
}

let df: DataFrame = ["Station": stations, "Values": values]

let grouped_df = df.grouped(by: "Station")

print(grouped_df.means("Values",Double.self).sorted(on:"Station"))
```

grouped_df.means() gives me a new dataframe with the mean of the values-column, but I need minimum and maximum, too.

Comment: have you tried using, for example:  `let min_df = grouped_df.minimums(ColumnID("Values", Double.self), order: .ascending)` to get the minimums. Similarly for maximums.

Comment: Thx for this suggestion. I'm hoping there would be a solution, which gives me all three new columns in one go...